# DLL file copies to the bin directory of one project, but not the other?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, shared-libraries, projects-and-solutions

I have a solution with 2 projects in it: ProjA and ProjB. ProjA is an application while ProjB is a library. ProjB also references 3 other DLL files (C, D, E). When I build ProjB C, D, and E all go into the bin directory. When I compile ProjA (which ONLY references ProjB) only C and D are copied, and not E.

I'm really not sure what would cause this to happen. I looked at the reference properties and all 3 (C, D, and E) are identical (except for their name and path). I guess I'm not sure why ProjB would place E into the bin directory, but when my application (ProjA) builds it does not copy E locally?

Comment: Can you post your vb/csproj here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and make a wild guess: reference E is not used directly by project B thus the reference does not appear in the PE manifest of project B's output.

Likely you have "Copy Local" on the references in Project B which explains why these assemblies are copied to the bin folder of project B.

However, if you were to open the dll for project B you will notice that reference E is not listed as an assembly dependency. Visual Studio / MSBuild cannot infer that Project A's usage of **assembly B** requires E.

To resolve the problem, use a class or feature of reference E in Project B.

Alternatively, have project A & B output their assemblies to a common folder. Tip: turn off "Copy Local" in this scenario to improve build performance.

---

**Update:**

I've tried several different ways to reproduce your problem but the closest I've got was from this [post which suggests that it may be a path probing problem](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Resolving-Binary-References-in-MSBuild.aspx). In the example provided the reference from A to B is a static file reference (bin\Debug\ProjB.dll) and the dependencies (E) are defined as Copy Local=False. The sample project is set up in such a way that all the dependencies have been compiled and packaged in the zip.

When you compile A, the problem you've described is noticeable. The fix, should be to change ProjB's E reference to "Copy Local=True", but if you make this change and recompile -- there's no difference! Why?

It seems as though changing the setting "Copy Local" doesn't actually change the output of ProjB in any way. And because the reference in ProjB is a static reference, it doesn't pick up that any changes have occurred. It's not until you do a Clean that the build compiles normally.

Don't know if that helps. Otherwise, good luck.

Comment: Actually I do use E in project B heavily, which is how I came to find out that it isn't copying. My application has a runtime error because the library is not copied to ProjA's bin whereas it is in ProjB's bin.

Comment: Interesting! I was expecting the runtime error but my assumption was that C or D needed E, but E's Types were not explicitly used in B, hence no direct IL reference to it. I'd like to reproduce this problem, can you share some more details about the references?

Comment: Well I'm going to try something out soon, I'm going to create a new solution with a similar project setup (fresh and clean) and see what happens. I have a feeling it might just be something funky going on with E.